# How to handle training of a CNN model with large dataset in the pickle format in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, large-data

I have a problem about handling big data in training large dataset in tensorflow.

I would like to train a simple CNN model. The input of my model is a lots of pickle files that inside them there are 1000 images and their labels.

So, it is clear that I have memory limitation and I can't train the model in one time. So, I found fit_generator method useful.
My pickle is unclude : image, label

This is my code:
I would like to know if my method and my code is correct? is my method standard for handling for example 1000 GB of data?

```
import os
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical



with open('configs.yaml', 'r') as file:
    configs = yaml.safe_load(file)

BucketsPATH = configs['path_management']['SaveBucket']

#Give the address of the pickle files
pickles_dir = os.listdir(BucketsPATH)   #Small buckets path
pickles_dir.sort()

filename_path_list = [os.path.join(BucketsPATH , item) for item in pickles_dir]


# Function to load data from a pickle file
def load_data_from_pickle(pickle_file):
    with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    return data['img'], data['label']

# Custom data generator
def data_generator(pickle_files, batch_size):
    while True:
        for pickle_file in pickle_files:
            images, labels = load_data_from_pickle(pickle_file)
            images = np.array(images)
            labels = np.array(labels)
            num_samples = len(labels)
            num_batches = num_samples // batch_size

            for batch_num in range(num_batches):
                start_idx = batch_num * batch_size
                end_idx = (batch_num + 1) * batch_size

                batch_images = images[start_idx:end_idx]
                batch_labels = labels[start_idx:end_idx]

                yield batch_images, batch_labels


train_data_generator = data_generator(filename_path_list, 32)
total_samples = sum(len(load_data_from_pickle(file)[1]) for file in filename_path_list)
steps_per_epoch = total_samples // 32

# Loop over the batches in the data generator
for step in range(steps_per_epoch):
    # Get the next batch of data
    batch_images, batch_labels = next(train_data_generator)
    print(batch_labels)
    # print(batch_images)

    # Do whatever you want with the batch of data
    # For example, you can print the shape of the batch
    print(f"Step: {step + 1}, Batch Images Shape: {batch_images.shape}, Batch Labels Shape: {batch_labels.shape}")
    

#CNN Model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.Input(shape= (60,60,3)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 2, activation='relu', padding='same'), 
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),    
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu' ),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid' )])
model.summary()


# # Compile the model
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=.9)
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae'])

model.fit_generator(
    train_data_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=10
)
```

I would like to know if my method and my code is correct? is my method standard for handling for example 1000 GB of data?